# Numbers which get reduced by 57 times on deleting the leading digit.

Tags: integers

If the leading digit of a positive integer is deleted, the number gets reduced by 57 times. Find all such numbers.

Comment: I mean, it's solved below, but where did you get the problem? Did you make it up? _For us?_

Comment: No, I found it in a book

Comment: Hm. Maybe you should have put it into the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$57\cdot n=10^r m+ n\iff56n=10^r m$$

$\iff8n=\dfrac{10^rm}7\implies 7\mid m, m=7q$(say)

As $0<m<10, m=7$

$\implies8n=10^r\implies r\ge3, n=5^r2^{r-3}$

Comment: Can you give me the detailed explanation!

Comment: @Hanzala, Put a few values of $r\ge3$ you should understand the steps